# How to get a state from a different component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to disable a button in `reactjs` depending on a value taken from a different component.

In below component (`main.js`), I need to disable the Button. But This has to be disabled depending on a value taken from a value **another component (`upload.js`)**

```
export default function HorizontalLabelPositionBelowStepper() {
  .
  .
  .
  return (
    <Grid container>      
      <Grid item lg="12" md="12" xs="12">
          <div className={classes.root}>                   
                <div>
                  <Grid container justify="center">                                      
                    <Grid item md="1">
                      <Button // button I need to disable
                        variant="contained"
                        color="secondary"
                        onClick={handleNext}
                        endIcon={<NavigateNext />}
                      >
                        {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "Finish" : "Next"} 
                      </Button>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </div>                         
          </div>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

And this is the `upload.js`

```
// imports...
.
.
.

export default function ElevateAppBar(props) {
  const [file, setFile] = useState('');
  const [filename, setFileName] = useState('eg: employees.csv'); // this filename value should be passed to the component `main.js`

  return (
    <Grid container justify="flex-start">
      <Grid container item lg="12" md="12">        
        <Grid item lg="4" md="4" xs="4">
          <Form>
            <Form.File id="custom-file" label={filename} custom />
          </Form>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>      
      <Grid container justify="center">
        <Button variant="contained" style={{backgroundColor: "lightgreen"}} endIcon={<CloudUpload />}>
          Upload
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

In the `upload.js` I have a variable with the name `filename`. I need to pass this value to the first component - that is `main.js`

so the logic could be like something (this is not reactjs syntaxes, this is just to give the idea on what I need to do):

```
if(filename_taken_from_upload_js == "eg: employees.csv"){
  // disable the button
}else{
  // enable the button
}
```

Can someone help, Please?

Comment: What is the connection between main.js and upload.js components?

Comment: No connection... @palaѕн

Answer (score 2):

This could be a case for lifting state up : https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up

If this value could be used by other unrelated components, you should consider putting it in a global state, using Redux or Context API.

https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#react-redux
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context

Comment: I am new to `ReactJs` can you provide me with an example, please, relevant to my scenario?

Comment: If upload.js is a direct child of main.js, just put filename variable in main.js state, then pass filename as a props to its child component (upload.js) along with a reference to a function which updates filename value in main.js. This is very common pattern in React. If upload.js is not a child of main.js then you must learn Context API or Redux, there is thousands of examples online to address this common use case. Good luck !

Comment: But this `context` only works when there is a component tree right? Since mine is not a component tree how can I do this?

Comment: Indeed you should have a root component, ancestor of all components. If it's not your case then it should be.